# Binding and unbinding events in vaadin 8

Tags: vaadin8

In my application I have multiple vertical layouts based on the backend data and in layout I have `RadioButtonGroup`

I want an easy way that if any particular layout is been clicked only the button inside that layout must be checked rest all the buttons must be uncheked.

I have made a separate class for that particular component like

```
Class Mylyt extends VerticalLayout{

Private RadioButtonGroup<String> radio = new RadioButtonGroup();

Mylyt(){
addcomponent(radio)}
}
```

The objects of this class will be created multiple times according to the backend data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You could register an `addLayoutClickListener` listener on your custom vertical layout. Once it's clicked, you could set/select the value only in the `RadioButtonGroup` of this layout.

So something along those lines:

```java
public class RadioButtonView  extends VerticalLayout{
    RadioButtonGroup<String> rbg=new RadioButtonGroup<>("RBG", Arrays.asList("First","Second","Third"));
    public RadioButtonView(){
        addComponent(rbg);
        this.addLayoutClickListener(e->{
           rbg.setValue("First");
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: It would be like the buttons would be initialized each time as the RadioButton View's multiple instance would be present.so for me its like somewhat hard to manage it